# Refactoring from WM_CONCAT to LISTAGG function

Tags: oracle11g

The oracle version has been updated and WM_CONCAT function stopped working.
I have to changed it for LISTAGG function but it takes only 2 arguments LISTAGG(measure_expr, delimiter)

What if there are two columns: `WM_CONCAT(COB.COD_COB||':'||COB_1.NOM_COB)` ?

I tried:

```
LISTAGG((COB.COD_COB||':'||COB_1.NOM_COB), ':') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY COB.COD_COB,COB_1.NOM_COB) AS COB_DESC
```

but it gives me an error

```
   SELECT DISTINCT

      -- TO_CHAR(WM_CONCAT(COB.COD_COB||':'||COB_1.NOM_COB)) AS COB_DESC,
      LISTAGG((COB.COD_COB||':'||COB_1.NOM_COB), ':') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY COB.COD_COB,COB_1.NOM_COB) AS COB_DESC

    FROM COBERTURAS_REDUCIDA_UW COB
    LEFT JOIN A1002150 COB_1 ON COB.COD_CIA = COB_1.COD_CIA
    GROUP BY COB.COD_CIA
```

Comment: Cannot replicate the problem [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=325eec6be42c3a56ef7e2e151e8695e7). Please [edit] your question to give a [MRE] including: the `CREATE TABLE` statements for your tables; the `INSERT` statements for some sample data that replicates the problem; the **FULL** text of the error; and your expected output.

Comment: `wm_concat()` only takes one argument; you're just constructing that argument via string concatenation - as you are with `listagg()`. If you're trying to replicate the same behaviour then you should make the delimiter a comma, not a colon. (Perhaps that is causing a problem when the resulting string is processed later, rather than the query you showed giving an error?) Without the information MTO already asked for, there isn't much else we can do to help.